# how to add only unique value into JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

how to add only unique value into JavaScript array?

Here is array i defined, below code adds duplicate value into array, but i do  NOT want to add the duplicate values if already exists in `ary`
  , any help?

```
var ary = [];
function setFavorite(name, value){
    var obj = {}; 
    obj[name] = value; 

    ary.push(obj);
    ....
    ....
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/pewn1d4m/7/)

Comment: ES6/ES2015 will include a `Set` class that provides for sets. What you're describing is more like a `Map` however.

Comment: Also this really doesn't have much to do with jQuery.

Comment: @Pointy updated question, SO suggested to put jquery tag.. Can we do same thing in core javascript ?  , can you please update fiddle, it helps to understand easily

Comment: use first sample from jdphenix - it really is the best solution and pure javascript :)

Comment: @Pointy Excellent point (no pun intended), and it's been a while since I've checked but it's got a pretty wide compatibility now too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EcmaScript 6 (which sorrily is not available yet) will have [native Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

However, as this is not what you currently want because nobody will be able to use your site, try a [Polyfill like this one](https://github.com/WebReflection/es6-collections) or make your code check the array for the value before insertion, for example using this code ([demo](http://jsbin.com/qiqupicufi/2/edit?js,console)):

```
function contains (array, value) {
  var doesContain = false

  for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === value) {
      doesContain = true
      break
    }
  }

  return doesContain
}
```

**EDIT:** Didn't read the code, just the description.

So actually what you want is a `Map`/an `Object`. Before setting a property of that Object, check if it already exists:

```
if (object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
  throw new Error('Hey, you have already set ' + prop + '!')
} else {
  obj[prop] = value
}
```

You can read more about `Object`s [here (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and [here (eloquent javascript book)](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html). The latter even has a section about using objects as maps.

Comment: Just stick with the second solution (with `obj.hasOwnProperty`). The `contains` thing is made for use with Arrays (`[]` notation), but you are using an Object (`{}` notation).

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid duplicate keys in your map (which is truly what you're describing here) by using a plain object.

```
var map = {}; 

function setFavorite(name, value) { 
    map[name] = value; 
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted an error upon attempting to enter a duplicate, instead of overwriting, you could:

```
 function setFavorite(name, value) { 
     if (map[name]) { 
         throw new Error('Cannot insert duplicate value'); 
     }
     map[name] = value; 
 }
```

**To retrieve** the value by key, you would access it by the property name you saved. Note that if the key value is a variable, you must use the array notation (with `[]` brackets).

```
  var value = map[key]
```

or,

```
  var value = map.keyHappenedToBeValidIdentifier
```

**To iterate** through the map, use `Object.keys`.

```
Object.keys(map).forEach(function(key) { 
    var value = map[key]; 
    // do some useful work with the value 
});
```

Comment: Sorr! Not helpful, i asked question to get answer in terms of array NOT using map. Please update your answer in respect to Array

Comment: With respect, *no*. An array isn't meant to hold unique entries. I'm not going to use a sledgehammer to do the task of a screwdriver.

Comment: you are right, if i knew this before then i could have used map instead of array, Now if i change this to map then entire code will get effected because they are fetching as array NOT map, what should i do in this situation, any suggestion?

Comment: Arrays are not designed to hold only unique values. I suggestion is to refactor to use a different data structure. If that's not possible, then you will have to write a custom function to handle avoiding duplicates.

Comment: yes, could you please give a example for custom method to check duplicates?